# SQL - Distinct entries with some cruddy data

Tags: t-sql

I have an issue. I have 2 tables that are linked by an ID.

```
TableA
   ID
   Price
   Other_Stuff

TableB
   ID
   TableA_ID
   Type
   Age
```

I can do a:

```
SELECT
   M1.Age,
   F1.Age,
   M2.Age,
   F2.Age,
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE TableB.Type='1') AS M1 ON M1.TableA_ID=TableA.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE TableB.Type='2') AS F1 ON F1.TableA_ID=TableA.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE TableB.Type='3') AS M2 ON M2.TableA_ID=TableA.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE TableB.Type='4') AS F2 ON F2.TableA_ID=TableA.ID
```

And things work as expected while the data is good, *but* the data is not always good. Normally there is at most one or none of each Type in TableB. The problem is that for older data in the table, before types 3 and 5 existed, there is the possibility that there are two type 1 and or two type 2s. in that case I would want the second type 1 to be treated as a type 2 and the second type 2 is treated as a type 4.

Basically I want a single record returned for each entry in TableA with the 4 ages listed in their own columns, I do not want multiple records for each in TableA.

I am using MS SQL 2000.... old, i know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try changing the subqueries to something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableB WHERE TableB.Type='1 AND TableA_ID=TableA.ID
```

Comment: I thought this too, but the result is that the first entry of the subquery is returned. based on the 1 returned record, the ON part of the join is used, so the end result is that all but 1 record of the overall query has an age, everything else is null.